# Cellcolor covers alignment character in tabular

Tags: tables, colortbl, cellcolor

I'm aligning a range of numbers on an en-dash between two columns in a tabular. I'd like to add color to alternating groups of rows, but using `\cellcolor` covers up the en-dash.

Note: this tabular is ultimately nested into one column of a larger tabular, so I haven't had much luck trying to use `\rowcolor` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\cc{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{--}l}
1 & 10 \\
\cc 11 & \cc 50 \\
51 & 1,000 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No need to load `colortbl` if you also load `xcolor` with the `table` option.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Thought my MWE was M enough already…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry the user interface isn't great, one simple version is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\cc{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{r>{--}l}
1 & 10 \\
\cc 11 & \cc 50 \\
51 & 1,000 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the excellent (and fast) [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn) package. Since a `dcolumn` is in math mode, you need [icomma](https://ctan.org/pkg/icomma) or similar package to avoid a space after the thousands separator. You also need to adjust the width of the column to compensate for the space the comma occupies. I added a small `tabcolsep`:

If you prefer `\textendash` instead of maths minus sign, just repalce the second hyphen with the command `\textendash`, eventually with some space before and after:

```
\newcolumntype{d}{D{-}{\textendash}{2,4}}
```

THe example below is set in maths mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn, array, icomma}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\cc{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}

\newcolumntype{d}{D{-}{-}{2,4}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{d}
1-10 \\
\cc11-50 \\
51-1,000 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've been playing with this solution, and I was wondering if there was a way to change the math mode minus sign to an en dash, specifically using unicode-math. It's pretty close as is, but coming here has made me sensitive to the distinction!

Comment: @SueDunham See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides tools to color cells. However, the colour is put using PGF/Tikz and, in your case, there is no disparition of the dash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\cc{\cellcolor[gray]{.7}}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{r@{--}l}[colortbl-like]
1 & 10 \\
\cc 11 & \cc 50 \\
51 & 1,000 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

**You need several compilations.**

[image: Output of the above code]